# How to solve magento migration duplicate entry error?

Tags: migration, magento2.3.2

I am doing migration as per the magento documentation. I am aware of all steps.

**while the execution of**

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.7/config.xml
```

**I'm getting below error:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '50575-50577' for key 'CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT  
  _ID'
```

**This is what I found in catalog_product_super_link table.**
[image]

I'm using fresh Magento 2.3.2 and migrating it.

**I think I want to delete one record but not sure.
50577 is an ID of configurable product and 50575 is id of simple product.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting one record will help, config product link with simple product through that table only needs 1 record.

Let me know if it works